# Unable to save entity when date is set

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot with JPA and Lombok.
My *Sample* entity contains four dates, the *approved* date, sample date, and a `createdAt` and `modifiedAt` that is maintained by JPA itself with the `Auditable` class. JPA manages the schema, database running MySQL and all the date columns are `DateTime`. All Dates are of class `java.util.Date`.

**Sample entity** (simplified for reasons)

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class Sample extends Auditable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id;

    Date approved;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'H:m")
    Date sampleDate;
}
```

The `DateTimeFormat` on the `sampleDate` is to help Spring convert form-data to a `java.util.Date`.

**Auditable.java**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Auditable {

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "modified_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modifiedAt;
}
```

When my controller performs this:

```
Sample s = sampleRepository.getOne(id);
s.setApproved(new Date());
sampleRepository.save(s);
```

Spring Generates this error message:

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'approved' at row 1

Comment: how does the Sample db schema look?

Comment: what is max-length of `approved` column?

Answer (score 0):

You would better use LocalDateTime instead of `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`, if you are doing this with java >= 8.

Audited entities' createdDate, lastModifiedDate should be set by Jpa Auditor(framework), not by client(in this context, you).

Also, you can try `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` instead of `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` if you want to keep your code.

### Updated

Sorry about I missed what exact subject you raised.

Just try add `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` above `Date approved;`.

Comment: Don't use `LocalDateTime`. It does not describe a point in time which you almost certainly want especially for the fields in `Auditable`. Consider `Instant` instead

Comment: @JensSchauder In different point of view, I agreed with your suggestion. However, for local service, it is easier to read time for using `LocalDateTime`. I think this argument is not proper in this question.